# Returning row if value exists, inserting otherwises

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that is created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
     p_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
     my_column varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (p_id),
     CONSTRAINT unique_mycolumn UNIQUE (mycolumn);
```

What I would like to do is return p_id if a particular value matches whatever is in my_column, but if not, insert that particular value and return the newly generated value. I can "sort" of get around this by trying to from within my code calling the respective queries to query the value, and if that returns null, insert it, but that's a fairly big race condition and I'd like to do it within sql. I've seen a lot of similiar questions, but this is different given the unique constraint on that column.

EDIT: This is what I'm looking to accomplish: Say I have the following data:

```
1 | foo
2 | bar
```

If I query for "bar", I'd like to get 2 back. However, If I query for "baz", I'd like to have the table look like the following:

```
1 | foo
2 | bar
3 | baz
```

So I guess it would be better described as "return ID if the value exists, and insert it the value otherwise to create a new row".

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. Can you add some sample data and the expected results based on that data

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
with ins as (insert into my_table (my_column)
select 'baz' where not exists 
   (select 1 from my_table where my_column = 'baz')
returning p_id)
select p_id from ins
union all 
select p_id from my_table where my_column = 'baz';
```

Note however that this can fail if two transactions try to insert the value 'baz' at the same time.